# ListView Header with dynamic TextVIew

Tags: android, listview, header

I have a problem with a ListView and a custom layout header.
This is the layout for the header. I want to use textView1 as a "title" for the header and I want to put the text inside it by code (To simplify the code I have removed some ImageView elements used in the frameLayout):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/top_height"
    android:background="#4038ed" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="[DYNAMIC TEXT]"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/White_FF" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/sticky_height" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for the fragment that is inflating the Header and putting the text inside the TextView:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = _context.getLayoutInflater();
    View mHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_requirements, null);
    header_idProyecto = (TextView) mHeader.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    header_idProyecto.setText(_oproyecto.get_codigoProyecto());
    _lstListado.addParallaxedHeaderView(mHeader);
```

The problem is with the TextView. It loads sucesfully the text injected by code but it appears at the right end of the view and the text is not visible (only the first letter is showed). When I tap the ListView with my finger, the TextView is showed correctly (the whole text appears, but I have not any code for that action).The desired effect is that the whole text appears when I put it by code. Is this a rendering problem?
I attach two screen captures (Sorry about the images, I had to hide some text and images because copyright reasons): The first one shows the TextView when I put the text by code (there are two textviews)
The second is what happends when I touch the ListView

```
Capture 1  
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B32lzJMHWRNsNkVLdHpMeUIzVVU&authuser=0  

Capture 2  
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B32lzJMHWRNsYlBzTUthLURMQ3M&authuser=0
```

Thank you in advance